# Automatically create Swift UILabels programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create UILabels in swift automatically based on need. I.e If my data base request returns 4 values, I want 4 labels, if it returns 1 value, i want 1 label..ect.

So far i have the code below, but it displays my data(Strings in an array on parse) on-top of each other in one label. I need a dynamic way to create new labels with different names, but am not sure how to do this. Currently this is my code. I have a 'spacer' variable that i hoped would push the next retrieved data in a label 50px below but it just pushes all the data in the same UILabel below by 50.

```
for comments in object["Comments"] as NSArray {
     var counter = ""   
     println(comments)
     counter = comments as String

       var spacer: CGFloat = 50
        var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        label.center = CGPointMake(160, 300 + spacer )
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = counter
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        spacer = spacer + 50
   }
```

I guess I need to create a new UILabel with a new name for every label(label1,label2..ect), but how can I do this dynamically, any suggestions?

Comment: You can use tag value of UILabel for each time creating labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the label doesn't matter. You spacer variable is reset on every loop iteration. Move this line:

```
var spacer: CGFloat = 50
```

before:

```
for comments in object["Comments"] as NSArray {
```

and it should be all good.

Comment: @user3438980 this is not the same UILable every loop iteration you create different label. The approach will be the same then.

Comment: Thank you Greg, i can't believe i missed that!